# finding max value of finishes per date

Tags: mysql, subquery

Pardon for the title, but I absolutely have no idea as to how to describe this.

I've got a table like this:

```
trackID playerID score   date
1        2       4510    1494075555
1        2       4507    1494076300
1        2       4513    1494076561
2        3       39455   1494083772
3        3       5665    1494089018
2        2       38444   1494074519
4        3       34443   1494089138
5        3       56443   1494260918
```

I want only the first finish per track, a track can have multiple players finish on the same date.
I want to have the max amount of first finishes on a single day.

In the table above, player 3 finished 3 maps for the first time on the 6.5.2017.
On the 8.5.2017 he only finished a single track. I only want to include the date he finished the most tracks.

Result I want:

```
playerID trackID count(trackID)  date
3        2,3,4       3           6.5.2017
2        1,2         2           6.5.2017
```

Comment: Fix the dates in your sample data.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? What is a first finish?

Comment: There is no track finishing details.

Comment: The data set isn't very representative. All tracks except one share the same (solitary) date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite ugly, but what can we do.
The sample size is increased to test the somewhat complicated alghorithym and to show the limits

So to better verify my results.

The table

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`trackID` int, `playerID` int, `score` int, `date` int)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`trackID`, `playerID`, `score`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 4510, 1494075555),
    (1, 2, 4507, 1494076300),
    (1, 2, 4513, 1494076561),
    (2, 3, 39455, 1494083772),
    (3, 3, 5665, 1494089018),
    (2, 2, 38444, 1494074519),
    (4, 3, 34443, 1494089138),
    (5, 3, 56443, 1494260918),
    (6, 3, 56443, 1494260928),
    (7, 3, 56443, 1494260938),
    (1, 4, 4510,1494324530),
    (2, 4, 4510,1494324530),
    (3, 4, 4510,1494324530),
    (4, 4, 4510,1494324530),
    (5, 4, 4510,1494324530),
    (6, 4, 4510,1494324530)
;
```

With this select statement

```
SELECT
  a4.trackID, a4.playerID, 
  MAX(
  a4.countgroup
  ) countgroup,
  MAX(
  CONCAT(day_a,".",month_a,".",year_a)
  )  `date`
FROM
(
   SELECT 
     Group_COnCAT(DISTINCT trackID) trackID,
     playerID
     , Count(*) countgroup 
     ,YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) year_a
     ,MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))  month_a
     ,DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))  day_a
   FROM
    (Select 
       DISTINCT trackID, playerID,MAX(`date`) `date`
     FROM table1
    GROUP by  playerID,trackID
    ) c1
  GROUP BY playerID,YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) 
         ,MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) ,DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))
 ) a4
inner join
( SELECT
   a2.playerID, a2.countgroup,a2.`date`
 FROM
 (
   SELECT playerID,  Count(*) countgroup, MAX(`date`) `date`
   FROM
    (
     Select 
       DISTINCT trackID, playerID,MAX(`date`) `date`
     FROM table1
     GROUP by  playerID,trackID
    ) c1
    GROUP BY playerID,YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) 
         ,MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) ,DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))
  ) a2 
   INNER JOIN
  (
  SELECT playerID,max(countgroup) maxcountgroup, MAX( `date`)  `date`
   FROM
   (
     SELECT playerID,  Count(*) countgroup, MAX( `date`)  `date`
      FROM
      (
        Select 
          DISTINCT trackID, playerID,MAX(`date`) `date`
        FROM table1
        GROUP by  playerID,trackID
      ) c1
      GROUP BY playerID,YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) 
         ,MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) ,DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))
    ) g1  
     GROUP BY playerID,YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) 
         ,MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) ,DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))
  ) a3
  ON a2.playerID = a3.playerID AND a3.maxcountgroup = a2.countgroup
    and YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(a2.`date`))  = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(a3.`date`)) 
     #and MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(a2.`date`)) = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(a3.`date`))
     #and DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(a2.`date`)) = DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(a3.`date`))
) b4
ON a4.playerID = b4.playerID AND a4.countgroup = b4.countgroup
GROUP BY playerID,trackID;
```

You will get following result

```
trackID         playerID    countgroup  date
1,2             2           2           6.5.2017
2,3,4           3           3           6.5.2017
5,6,7           3           3           8.5.2017
1,2,3,4,5,6     4           6           9.5.2017
```

This is complicated:
So in table a4 i get the needed data, but there are for every player multiple days and i have to choose the days that have the most won tracks.

There enters table b4, which selects for every player the date and most tracks reached.

The problem as you can see in the example is, when there are two or more days with the same number of tracks conquered.

Here is the dbfiddle example so that you can test it
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=88bb4f9c208ccf6a9865b79b1681faa5

edit2: had to add date column to the SEELCT and on clause of b4

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the reply. You almost got what I wanted, so I hope you'll be able to get it exactly how I wanted: In my example, playerID 3 finished 3 tracks on the 06.05.2017, and 1 track on the 08.05.2017, instead of showing the count of 4 for the 08.05.2017, like in your result, I only want the 3 finished Tracks of the 06.05.2017, because I only need the highest amount of tracks finished by day. I'm not even sure whether a query like that is possible, hence why I asked. Thanks for your efforts, appreciate it.

Comment: O, now i understand why there are three tracks, but how do i determine which is finished. Bcause player 2 reached track 2 but not track 3 , player3 has reached track 5 but not 6. So why has player 2 finished track 2 but payer 3 not track 5

Comment: basically, if a track is finished, it'll receive a score.
for example. player 2 finishes track 1, it gets a score and date(the unixtime) of when it happened.
if player 2 finishes track 1 again, it will again get a score and a date. hence why player 2 has multiple scores on track 1.
I only want each track once per player tho, associated with the earliest date.
player 2 may not have finished trackID 3 yet, but could finish it at a later date. i
hope that clears stuff, it's quite hard to explain. thank you for your efforts nonetheless.

Comment: that doesn't explain why payer 3 hasn't finished Round 5 . in your table the last entry is (**5**,** 3**, 56443, 1494260918) so that means by your explanation **player 3 has finished Round 5 with score 56443 and at 8th of May**

Comment: indeed, player 3 finished track 5 at the 8th of may. But he finished tracks 2,3,4 on the 6th of may, so I only want to keep the date where he finished the most tracks, in this case the 6th of may.

Comment: So i changed it once more, see the results carefully and i added als a dbfiddle to play with. I hope you have many friends that upvote this

Comment: This seems to be it, thanks! It sadly doesn't work in my actual database, and I don't know why, whenever I run it, it skips some playerIDs, when using a smaller table it's however working again, this is frustrating, but not your problem, I thank you very much for your efforts and have accepted the answer.

Comment: use the fiddle and add there the not appearing rows. if  it also there happens, write here and link it and i wwill see what i can do

Comment: the query at the bottom of my fiddle is the result I need: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0f7bab3b5d7354b8dc4cc496fb16938c , as you can see, it counts 12 tracks for the 14.08.2019, because that's when the tracks got finished first. (it's actually supposed to be 13, but I think that's because the database uses a different timezone than my local one) if I add limit 1 to the query, it's the result I want, however, I can't use it because it needs to have the playerID specified (WHERE playerID = 797) which means I'd have to query each playerID individually, I don't want that.

Comment: the whole thing is very complex, so once again, I thank you for you efforts, but I think this isn't manageable

Comment: I changed it to fit with the new data. Look such complex SQL statements have usually their kings, you see that because of that  every body formats the statements, to have easy debug possibilit. Try the new select statement.